# How to display items in Rules data selector in alphabetical order

Tags: 7, rules

Because of my sites having a lot of fields, it takes me a lot of time to select fields in the Rules data selector, because they are sorted by date created.
What should I do to make them sorted alphabetically?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer in any way, but

on around line 150 of rules.autocomplete.js, there is this code..

```
  Drupal.rules.autocomplete.prototype.success = function(data, request, response) {
    var list = new Array();
    jQuery.each(data, function(index, value) {
      list.push( {
        label: value,
        value: index
      });
    });

    this.cache[request.term] = list;
    response(list);
  };
```

That could possibly be where you need to add some code to rearrange the list. It might be there or it might be elsewhere.. It's a huge module.

If you manage it, create a patch for yourself that can be applied each time the module is updated.